# i want to display msql table by puting the filter on drop down menu in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

as the code below is accesing the database table directly but i want it to display the table content on giving conditions in drop down menu like when i select islamabad in one drop down menu and lahore in other as given in code and press search buttonn then it display the table flights.but it is displaying it directly

```
<p class="h2">Quick Search</p>
    <div class="sb2_opts">
     <p>
   </p>
<form method="post" action="haseeb.php">
 <p>Enter your source and destination.</p>
<p>
    From:</p>
<select name="from">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<p>
    To:</p>
   <select name="To">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search" /> 
</form>
</form> </table>

<?php



$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';


$database = 'homedb';
$table = 'flights';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");
$whereClauses = array(); 
if (! empty($_POST['from'])) $whereClauses[] ="from='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from'])."'"; 
if (! empty($_POST['To'])) $whereClauses[] ="To='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['To'])."'"; 
$where = ''; 
if (count($whereClauses) > 0) { $where = ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ',$whereClauses); } 


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");


}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: I can haz better explanation, ook?

Comment: whould u please answer this?? thanks @karlingen

Comment: You will have to give us a better explanation. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Seriosly, who upvotes this stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your tables are getting displayed before you submit the form is because you are directing the form to the same page and not validating them with conditional statements. Try encoding your php codes that are outputting to the screen inside an if validation.

```
if($_POST)
{
   echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
   echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
   {
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach($row as $cell)
          echo "<td>$cell</td>";
      echo "</tr>\n";
   }
}
```